# Making a quiz in Javascript, only takes "Yes" and not "yes"

Tags: javascript

So im learning javascript and decided to make a quiz for fun, I ran into the problem when I made the quiz and it asked for answers it would only take 'Yes' and not 'yes' example...

```
var questions = [
['Do you like Pizza', 'Yes']
 ];

function askQuestion(question) {
var answer = prompt(question[0],'');
    if (answer == question[1]) {
        alert('Correct!');
        score++;
    } else { 
        alert('Sorry the correct answer is ' + question[1]);
        }
} 
for (var i=0;i<questions.length; i++) {
    askQuestion(questions[i]);
}
```

It will only take the answer with a capital Y, I know its a bad example. But I think you know what im saying.

Comment: Where's the actual code for the quiz?

Comment: "But I think you know what im saying." - not really. Your question doesn't have any actual code, or, in fact, a *question*

Comment: [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: Without seeing code, we can only guess at the cause of your problem.

Comment: if it's a "Yes/No" question, with a known set of possible answers, why even make them type it in? give them a checkbox or radio buttons.

Comment: It has to do with case sensitivity, change the case with variable_name = variable_name.toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to go ahead and post what seems to be the obvious - you are accepting a string and comparing it to "Yes", but you need to set the letter case for both values as the same, and then compare. So for example:

```
var questions = [
    ['Do you like Pizza', 'Yes']
];

var input = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
if (input.toLowerCase() == questions[i][1].toLowerCase()) {
    // `input` was "yes", "yEs", "Yes", etc.
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Now that you shared your actual code, change your function to this:

```
function askQuestion(question) {
    var answer = prompt(question[0],'');
    if ((""+answer).toLowerCase() == (""+question[1]).toLowerCase()) {
        alert('Correct!');
        score++;
    } else { 
        alert('Sorry the correct answer is ' + question[1]);
    }
}
```

Note how I converted both the user's answer and the question's correct answer to strings (to make sure you can actually call `toLowerCase`, since it only applies to strings), and then called `toLowerCase` on both.

Comment: Awesome that worked perfect. Sorry about not posting the whole thing for you guys first time on stackoverflow. Will make sure I provide all information next time.

Comment: @JoshDiChello No problem, it was your first question. Just trust me, provide as much relevant information/code as you can with a question - otherwise, people will go nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I would take your answer and the users answer and make them both lower case using the .toLowerCase() method.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30522577/quiz.html here is the file drop boxed.

Comment: Yeah so when you are you taking in the users answer like so `var answer = prompt("Are you gay?")` you would then use `if(answer.toLowerCase() == questions[0][1].toLowercase())`

Comment: @kbsurfer Good question to use as an example :)